# Newbie on debian and trying to make Java 7 the default java version used

Tags: linux, debian

2 questions.

1. After installing the Oracle Java 7 on my new Debian local box, I opened up a terminal and executed the following command:

java -version

When I did that it states:  java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

I installed the Java 7 JDK and Java 7 JRE in the following directories respectively:

/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0
/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0

1. Is there a way to remove the java-6-sun and java-6-sun-1.6.0.26 folders as well or will it hurt just to leave them there?

Any help/direction on these 2 questions would be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> sudo update-alternatives --config java

Is the command to swap it i believe.

You can then call

> which java

and it should reference the version selected.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I sure appreciate the quick response.  That got it!

Comment: no problem, i'm a huge ubuntu fan and ubuntu essential uses the deb. package system, so i took a wild stab in the dark :)

Answer (score 3):

`sudo update-java-alternatives -s ...` will configure all the alternatives at the same time
`update-java-alternatives -l` lists the alternatives

Comment: This is actually the command needed for stuff that uses JAVA_HOME environment variable